# Insert into windows keyboard buffer

Tags: c#, windows, input, keyboard

We need to read data from a piece of hardware (an RFID scanner) and inject it into the windows keyboard buffer. This is so that the RFID scanner can be used to capture a string and inject wherever the cursor currently is, so for example, if a text box in a windows app has focus, then that's where the string appears. If a text box in a web application rendered via a web browser has focus, the input needs to appear there.

Please be aware: the question is NOT about reading the data from the RFID device - we can do this, it's about putting the string we read into the windows keyboard buffer so that no matter which app has focus, the input appears at the cursor.

The development environment is C# .NET

Many thanks

Tony

Comment: I wonder if you'd be better off writing a HID driver for your RFID scanner. I have a simple barcode scanner that does this, and it works really well: as far as the computer is concerned, it's just another keyboard.

Comment: If the target windows is focused cant you just SendKeys.Send ?

Comment: I like both ideas, though of course the latter looks easier :-)

Comment: +1 to writing a driver; that's what they are for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply SendKeys.SendWait() or SendInput. Use SendKeys if you just want to send keystrokes to an active application in windows.